# Convert string with long month name to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have this string `July 1, 2021 9:10 AM` and I'm trying to parse it into a `DateTime` variable.

This isn't working for me. `ST` is a variable that has the string representation of the date and time.

```
var Event = DateTime.ParseExact(ST, "MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong day format. For a month day without a leading zero, you should use the following:

```
var Event = DateTime.ParseExact(ST, "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: And `d` also covers days like `01` anyway. :)